# Download files from set of folders on FTP/SFTP server with WinSCP .NET assembly in PowerShell and email results

Tags: powershell, ftp, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have this PowerShell script that I'm working on. CSV file is imported to get source and destination paths. The goal is to move files from a SFTP/FTP server into a destination and send an email report.

Task scheduler will run this code every hour. And if there's a new file, as email will be sent out.

It's almost done, but two things are missing:

- Check if the file already exists and Body email seems empty: Getting the following error:  Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Body'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not
  null or empty, and then try the command again.
- I would like some assistance on how to check if the file exists and how to get this email if a new file was dropped and copied to the destination list

```
$SMTPBody = ""

$SMTPMessage  = @{
  "SMTPServer" = ""
  "From" = ""
  "To" = ""
  "Subject" = "New File"
}
try {
  # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
  Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"

  # Setup session options
  $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::sftp
    HostName = ""
    UserName = ""
    Password = ""
    PortNumber = "22"
    FTPMode = ""
    GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = $true
  }
  $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
  try
  {
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)
    # Download files
    $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
    $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary

    Import-Csv -Path "D:\FILESOURCE.csv" -ErrorAction Stop |  foreach {

      $synchronizationResult = $session.SynchronizeDirectories(
        [WinSCP.SynchronizationMode]::Local, $_.Destination, $_.Source, $False)
      $synchronizationResult.Check()

      foreach ($download in $synchronizationResult.Downloads ) {
        Write-Host "File $($download.FileName) downloaded" -ForegroundColor Green
        $SMTPBody +=
          "`n Files: $($download.FileName -join ',    ') `n" +
          "Current Location: $($_.Destination)`n"
        Send-MailMessage @SMTPMessage  -Body $SMTPBody
      }

      $transferResult =
        $session.GetFiles($_.Source, $_.Destination, $False, $transferOptions)
      #Find the latest downloaded file
      $latestTransfer =
        $transferResult.Transfers |
        Sort-Object -Property @{ Expression = { (Get-Item $_.Destination).LastWriteTime }
        } -Descending |Select-Object -First 1
    }

    if ($latestTransfer -eq $Null) {
      Write-Host "No files found."
      $SMTPBody += "There are no new files at the moment"
    }
    else
    {
      $lastTimestamp = (Get-Item $latestTransfer.Destination).LastWriteTime
      Write-Host (
        "Downloaded $($transferResult.Transfers.Count) files, " +
        "latest being $($latestTransfer.FileName) with timestamp $lastTimestamp.")
      $SMTPBody += "file : $($latestTransfer)"
    }

    Write-Host "Waiting..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
  }  
  finally
  {
    Send-MailMessage @SMTPMessage  -Body  $SMTPBody
    # Disconnect, clean up
    $session.Dispose()
  }
}
catch
{
  Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your code has more problems than you think.

- Your combination of `SynchronizeDirectories` and `GetFiles` is suspicious. You first download only the new files by `SynchronizeDirectories` and then you download all files by `GetFiles`. I do not think you want that.
- On any error the `.Check` call will throw and you will not collect the error into your report.
- You keep sending partial reports by `Send-MailMessage` in the foreach loop

This is my take on your problem, hoping I've understood correctly what you want to implement:

```
$SMTPBody = ""

Import-Csv -Path "FILESOURCE.csv" -ErrorAction Stop |  foreach {

    Write-Host "$($_.Source) => $($_.Destination)"
    $SMTPBody += "$($_.Source) => $($_.Destination)`n"

    $synchronizationResult =
        $session.SynchronizeDirectories(
            [WinSCP.SynchronizationMode]::Local, $_.Destination, $_.Source, $False)

    $downloaded = @()
    $failed = @()
    $latestName = $Null
    $latest = $Null
    foreach ($download in $synchronizationResult.Downloads)
    {
        if ($download.Error -eq $Null)
        {
            Write-Host "File $($download.FileName) downloaded" -ForegroundColor Green
            $downloaded += $download.FileName
            $ts = (Get-Item $download.Destination).LastWriteTime
            if ($ts -gt $latest)
            {
                $latestName = $download.FileName;
                $latest = $ts
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "File $($download.FileName) download failed" -ForegroundColor Red
            $failed += $download.FileName
        }
    }

    if ($downloaded.Count -eq 0)
    {
        $SMTPBody += "No new files were downloaded`n"
    }
    else
    {
        $SMTPBody += 
            "Downloaded $($downloaded.Count) files:`n" +
            ($downloaded -join ", ") + "`n" +
            "latest being $($latestName) with timestamp $latest.`n"
    }

    if ($failed.Count -gt 0)
    {
        $SMTPBody += 
            "Failed to download $($failed.Count) files:`n" +
            ($failed -join ", ") + "`n"
    }

    $SMTPBody += "`n"
}
```

It will give you a report like:

```
/source1 => C:\dest1`
Downloaded 3 files:
/source1/aaa.txt, /source1/bbb.txt, /source1/ccc.txt
latest being /source1/ccc.txt with timestamp 01/29/2020 07:49:07.

/source2 => C:\dest2
Downloaded 1 files:
/source2/aaa.txt
latest being /source2/aaa.txt with timestamp 01/29/2020 07:22:37.
Failed to download 1 files:
/source2/bbb.txt
```

Comment: I saw where i made the mistakes and thank you for putting the output.

Answer (score 1):

To check and make sure the csv file exists before you process the entire thing, you can use the Test-Path,

```
    ...
    if (!(Test-Path D:\FileSource.csv)) {
        Write-Output "No File Found"
        $SMTPBody += "There are no new files at the moment"
        return; # Dont run. file not found. Exit out.
    }

    Import-Csv -Path "D:\FILESOURCE.csv" -ErrorAction Stop |  foreach {
    ...
```

and for the Body error you are getting, it is coming from the finally loop because there are cases where `$SMTPBody` would be null. This will no longer be an issue because $SMTPBody will have some text when file is not found at the beginning.

Even though you are using `return` in the if statement to check if the file exists, `finally` will always get executed. Since we updated $smtpbody, your `Send-MailMessage` will no longer error out.

**Update**

If you want to check if the file you are downloading already exists, you can use the if statement like this,

```
foreach ($download in $synchronizationResult.Downloads ) {
    if (!(Test-Path Join-Path D: $download.FileName) {
        $SMTPBody += "File $($download.Filename) already exists, skipping."
        continue # will go to the next download...
    }
    Write-Host "File $($download.FileName) downloaded" -ForegroundColor Green
    ...
```

If you do get the error regarding body, thats mostly because your script came across an exception and was sent straight over to `finally` statement. `Finally` statement sends the email with empty body because it was never set (due to exception). I would recommend using the debugger (step through) and see which step causes the exception and look into adding steps to make sure script doesnt fail.

Comment: CSV file has a Source and Destination list. Im not checking if the csv file exists. I have to check if files  exits inside of Destination folder $_.Destination

Comment: @user91 see update to the post above. Hopefully thats what you're looking for

Comment: Also the `foreach ($download in $synchronizationResult.Downloads )` must be within  the `Import-Csv -Path "D:\FILESOURCE.csv" -ErrorAction Stop |  foreach {` block, otherwise you will process only the downloads of the last synchronization.

Comment: @Joe i dont need that on my email body - skipping file that exists - if file exists ( dont download) and then download if theres a new file.. Thats where im stuck. Also your fixed doesnt seem right - join path

Comment: The `Test-Path` check makes no sense. It happens after the synchronization. So the file will always exist. Well, unless you check actually for a different file. I do not see the purpose of `Join-Path D:`.